# Как сделать проверку reCAPTCHA?

Tags: php, recaptcha

Как в рекапче проверить прошел юзер проверку или нет?
Для тех кто не в курсе:
Как отправить POST запрос на url: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
с параметрами: secret, response, remoteip?
И полученный ответ сервера с этого запроса (там выдает json), раскодировать и отправить по переменным?

Гугл не помог, прошу примеров. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

рекапча принимает get запросы

```
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOU_SECRET_KEY&response='.(array_key_exists('g-recaptcha-response', $_POST) ? $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"] : '').'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$resp = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

if ($resp['success'] == true) {
//все хорошо 
}
else {
// капча не решена
}
```

нужно, чтобы капча была в самой форме, где у вас все инпуты

Answer (score 1):

```
$rCode = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$rUrl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$rSecret = 'Твой секретный ключ';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$curl = curl_init($rUrl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'secret='.$rSecret.'&response='.$rCode.'&remoteip='.$ip);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$res = json_decode($res);

if ($res->success) {
    //Капча введена верно
    ....
} else {
    //Это бот или человек который не умеет пользоваться капчой
    ....
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Это правильный ответ. CURL, POST, ответ в виде json. Что именно нужно комментировать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = new CurlHelper([
    CURLOPT_URL => GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_VALIDATE_URL,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        'secret'    => GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response'  => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        'remoteip'  => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    ]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
]);

$result = $curl->send();
$validation = json_decode($result['content']);
if (empty($validation->success) || $validation->success === false) {
    $errors['captcha'] = 'invalid';
}
```